# Godot HTTPRequest send data to php website always is null at php web

Tags: php, httprequest, godot

I have been follow [godot documentation](https://docs.godotengine.org/ko/latest/tutorials/networking/http_request_class.html) to send data to my server. The connection is okay, but the data sent to my php web is always null. Anyone please guides me on this.

my godot codes:

```
func _make_post_request(url, data_to_send, use_ssl):
   var query = JSON.print(data_to_send)
   var headers = ["Content-Type: application/json"]
   $HTTPRequest.request(url, headers, use_ssl, HTTPClient.METHOD_POST, query)


func _on_Button_pressed():
    _make_post_request("http://localhost/buymall/site/test","Hello World",false)


func _on_HTTPRequest_request_completed(result, response_code, headers, body):
    var json = JSON.parse(body.get_string_from_utf8())
    print(json.result)
    print(result)
    print(response_code)
    print(body.get_string_from_ascii())
```

my php codes:

```
public function actiontest()
{
    $value = array(
        'value'=>$_POST
    );
    if(isset($_POST) && $_POST!=null)
    {
        echo json_encode($value);
    }else
    {
        echo "no post value";
    }
}
```

The outcome when i press POST button is always return "no post value" from my php site. What are the things i did wrong?

Comment: Is _POST used with application/json content type? What outputs when you `echo file_get_contents("php://input");`?

Comment: @hola Thanks for that clue!! `echo file_get_contents("php://input");` return me exactly the same string "Hello World". So the problem is I din send any json format string to the php site?

Comment: I think the `$_POST` variable isn't used for the `application/json` content type. If you know the body will be json for this request use `json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));` and check if it successfully decoded.

Comment: @hola Big Thanks! You are my life saver! Feel free to wrote this as answer for this question!